# App ratings adjusted for numbers of votes?

Tags: app-ratings

Rankings of apps by rating are typically useless because the app ratings are not adjusted for numbers of votes, and therefore the top of the ranking is invariably saturated with many screenfuls of 5-star apps each having only a handful of votes, thus obscuring apps with slightly lower ratings but much higher numbers of votes.  Needless to say, the latter ratings are vastly more reliable.  *These* are the apps I'm trying to find.

Does anyone know of an Android app search service that allows ranking results by app ratings somehow adjusted for numbers of votes?  (E.g. use the standard rating minus 1 or 2 standard deviations.)